# The Departed reference in How I Met Your Mother

Tags: dialogue, reference, how-i-met-your-mother, the-departed

In HIMYM, there's a continual reference to the movie Departed in the dialogue between Ted and Marshall, which goes like: "-Are you a cop? -I'm not a cop."

You can watch the scene [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOmh07MvwNg), which is from the thirteenth episode of the season 8.

My question is that whether this specific (or a similar) dialogue appears in the movie, or it is merely an adaptation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar dialogue definitely appears in the movie in relation to Billy (DiCaprio), an undercover cop that tries to infiltrate crime boss Costello's crew. This is first invoked by his cousin, drug dealer Sean:

> Billy: In your line of work, if I gave you like, what, say, 10,000, what could I get back?
>
> Sean: You know what you usually say at these moments.
>
> [...]
>
> Billy: I'm not a cop, all right?

Later, Costello tortures Billy to make sure of it (this is probably the scene referenced on HIMYM):

> Costello: Are you still a cop?
>
> Billy: No! No!
>
> Costello: Swear on your mother's grave you're still not a cop.
>
> Billy: I am not a f*&%ing cop!

Ted and Marshall are distorting the quote, but it's a [common practice](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/List_of_misquotations).